# Filter values in database

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am looking for someone to explain how to filter a ms-access database by column and display only cells which have higher values than given value from textbox?

Example: If given value in textbox is 3:

```
Column1
1
2
3
4
5
```

Filtering...

```
Column1
4
5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to a form in a query:

```
SELECT Column1
FROM ATable
WHERE Column1 > Forms!AForm!txtTextbox
```

You can also apply a filter to a form, for the current form, you might say:

```
Private Sub txtTextbox_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Filter = "Column1>" & Me.txtTextbox
    Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```