# VB running sql query/filter database using text box text changed

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, filter

Currently I have an access database imported using datagridview. There are multiple columns
Say I wish to filter a column using a text box
I want the datagridview to filter in real time as the user types into the text box.

How do i do this? Is it using sql query? I am a beginner

Thanks

Comment: With Stack Overflow you should really at least have a basic knowledge of how to do it, show us what you have tried or what you are stuck on and then we can help. It was not meant for "show me how to code ____". So please show us what you have tried. At the very least post your code on how you populate your gridview

Comment: At least do some search on google or here at SO before you post, I am sure you will find something similar to start with. Hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725470/filter-values-in-database) link will help you

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is if you have coded it there is a method called keypress in textbox just double click it and change the method to keypress.

post me a reply back if you want to know how to code i will be glad to help.

regards.